# Date functions with $select in REST API

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, rest, office365apis

I'm using the following REST call to get the data. Here is the url structure:

```
SiteURL+'/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\''ListTitle+'\')/items?$select=AlternateThumbnailUrl,Title,Created
```

this is returning the 'Created' values as text ("2013-09-23T23:56:46Z"). My requirement is to get hours and minutes data as well. I'm not able to use REST day(Created), hour(Created), minute(Created) functions in `$select` parameter (getting 400 bad request error). Can anyone suggest to me a way to get the hours and minutes data using REST?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the date time string returned into javascript datetime object, and extract the information required. Take a look at this [link](http://www.apachebite.com/2012/09/04/javascript-parsing-iso-8601-date-string-to-local-date-time/)

```
var date = new Date("2013-09-23T23:56:46Z");
```